# Sequence of defined functions converging to something perhaps not defined

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$, where
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \textrm{ if $x<0$}\\
      nx & \textrm{ if $0\leq x\leq 1/n$} \\
      1 & \textrm{ if $x> 1/n$} \\
   \end{cases} $$
Now for all $n\in \mathbb{N} \ \ f_n(x)$ is defined and continous at $x=0$. Now if this sequence converges it seems to me that it would converge to a 1-to-many relation, so therefore it doesn't converge to a function, or it converges to a function undefined at $x=0$. So am I right in saying that this sequence of functions is not convergent? Or if it does converge then it converges to a discontinued function? If so, which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$, so the sequence does converge at $0$. But the limiting function is $f(x)=0$ if $x\leq 0$, $f(x)=1$ if $x>0$, so you are correct in saying that it is not continuous.